# MsDeploy not populating parameters using -setParam and getting error "argument cannot be null or empty"

Tags: msdeploy

I'm using MSDeploy to deploy an application via IIS Import, and via command line.

I'm setting a parameter that cannot be null, by setting defaultValue property as empty string. I'm also specifying that is an Enumerable, and the possible values.

Here is what my parameters.xml file has:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="MyKey" description="Please select a value from the list" defaultValue="">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='MyKey']/@value">
    </parameterentry>
    <parameterValidation kind="Enumeration" validationString="value1,value2,value3"/>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Working via IIS Import Application option works perfect, but when using the command line using the following command:

```
msdeploy -source:package='C:\Package\MyApp.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://example.com:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=MyIISSite",authtype="NTLM",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Package\MyApp.SetParameters.xml" -whatif -setParam:name=MyKey,value=value1 -enableRule:AppOffline -allowUntrusted
```

throws the error "The 'MyKey' argument cannot be null or empty".

Isn't -setParam an option to supply values for the parameters specified in parameters.xml file? It works if I set a default value to one of the allowed options when defining the parameter, but don't want to have any value by default in there.